# Relating two definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

> Let $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^{2021}}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1-x^{2021})^{a}}$$
> then find $a$

This is one of the questions of the *HOTS* section of my practice sheet. I can not think of any way to solve it. I got some hint from limits of the integrals which made me substitute $x^\frac{2021}{2}=\tan t$ and $ x^\frac{2021}{2}=\sin t$ in first and second integral respectively which made both of their limits same. However this made the integrals more messier as I tried to substitute the expressions for $dx$ in both.

Any helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your substitution

$$x^\frac{2021}{2}=\tan t\implies x={(\tan t)}^{\frac{2}{2021}}$$

The integral on LHS becomes

$$I_1=\frac{2}{2021}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{{(\tan t)}^{\frac{2019}{2021}}}$$

Using your substitution

$$x^\frac{2021}{2}=\sin t\implies x={(\sin t)}^{\frac{2}{2021}}$$

The integral on RHS becomes

$$I_2=\frac{2}{2021}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{(\cos t)^{1-2a}dt}{{(\sin t)}^{\frac{2019}
{2021}}}$$

Compare both of them to get

$$\boxed{a=\frac{1}{2021}}$$

Comment: Yeah , I was really very close, Thanks :-)